# How do I call for individual fields of a document saved in a variable in mongoDB Ruby driver?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Here is the code I am trying to replicate in ruby:

```
a = db.play.findOne({}, {_id: 0})
db.test.find({$and: [{address: a.address}, {name: a.name}]})
```

And that's how I am trying to do it:

```
collectio = db.collection("play")
a = collectio.find_one({}, {:fields => {"_id" => 0}})
collectio.find({"$and" => [{"address" => a.address}, {"name" => a.name}]})
```

I keep receiving a mistake that "address" method is not identified. I tried to put a.address into quotes, doesn't help. Do you know how can I make this work?

Comment: Do all your records have a field named `address` ?

Comment: Which gem are you using? What happens if you try a[:address] and a[:name]. The error should also specify the object class that doesn't define address, what is the exact error?